# MongoDB connection error after deploying MEAN App to Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, deployment, mean-stack

I am trying to deploy this app to Heroku, but when deploying the app to heroku I am getting the following error:

**Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.**

On the logs I am getting the following:

[image: heroku logs after deployment]

This is the url of the app: [app url](https://xon.herokuapp.com/)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong port. Wherever you assign your port variable try this instead:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

and feed that `port` variable into wherever you are setting your server to listen

Answer (score 0):

Do `heroku config`. Which one is your Mongo environment variable?

- `MONGOHQ_URL`,
- `MONGODB_URI`,
- `MONGOLAB_URI`?

Update your code with the right one, at the time of writing it is:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
```